# Using nested loops to find the mximum

Tags: c++, loops, max, nested-loops

> Blockquote

I am trying to make a program that finds the maximum of a function f(x) over an interval a<=x <=b by starting at x=a with a step size of Δx.I want to evaluate f1=f(x) and f2= f(x+Δx. If f1< f2, I should replace x with x+Δx and continue; otherwise, I should reduce the step size by half and repeat the comparison. The program should terminate successfully when Δ<10^-6.

Something in my program isn't right, I think it has to do with the user entering the equation, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Any suggestions?
Here's the code I've written so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int a, b, delta, fx, x, y;
int max = 0;

cout <<"Please complete the equation to be evluated f(x)= " << endl;
cin >> fx;
cout <<"Please enter the first number of the interval to be checked: " << endl;
cin >> a;
cout << "Please enter the last number of the interval to be checked: " << endl;
cin >> b;
cout << "Please enter the desired initial step size: " << endl;
cin >> delta;

  for(x = a; x <= b; x = x+delta) 

{
    y = fx;     
    if (y > max)  
    { 
        max = y;  
        cout <<"The maximum over the interval from " << a <<"to " << b <<"is " << delta;
    }
    else
    {
        delta= delta/2;
    }
    if (delta <  pow( 10, -6))
    {system ("PAUSE");}
}      


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: loop over all values from `a` to `b` with increment `Δx`.. At each iteration, evaluate function `f(x)`..check if it is the maximum until now

Comment: you are missing one `}`

Comment: +1 ysakamoto -- I ~fixed the indentation, it help illustrate this.

Comment: are you sure `x++= x++/2;` is valid?

Comment: That is not valid C++. First, try to compile it. Then try to debug it, then ask a question.

Comment: What in the world do you *think* this means?  `for(a<= x, x<= b, x++;)`?? Whatever you think, that is just C++ gibberish.

Comment: Looks like you massively edited the question and changed all the source-code (without explanation or comment).   We cannot answer question that keeps changing.

Answer (score 1):

Progress from Pseudo-code to real-code:

---

**Pseudo-Code:**

- Maximum starts at Negative Infinity (so that *every* number is bigger)
- X starts at A
- For Every Point X, (until X is at B), move X by delta-X

  - Evaluate f(x).
  - Compare f(x) against Maximum: if f(x) is bigger, Store that value in Maximum
- Continue Loop
- Show Results.

---

**Sorta-Code**:

```
{
    int max = INT_MIN;  // Maximum starts at Negative Infinity (or as close as I can get)

    for(x = a; x <= b; x = x+delta) // X starts at A
                                    // for Every Point X (until B)
                                    // move X by Delta.
    {
        y = f(x);     // Evaluate f(x)
        if (y > max)  // Compare f(x) against Maximum)
        { 
            max = y;  // if f(x) is bigger, store that value
        }
    }                 // Continue Loop
}
```

---

**Real-Code**

***(you fill it in... the Pseudo-Code and Sorta-Code have most of what you need)***

Really, that should be enough to get you moving.